# fadeIn after jQuery post

Tags: jquery

I have three forms on one page - "callback", "contact us" and "newsletter subscription".

Each has it's own jQuery function to "post" the data (using `.post`) and then display any returned PHP. These forms only output simple error and successes depending on the form and the process.

Now, here is where it gets a bit odd... all three of my forms work but only two work as expected:

1. Response DIV hides
2. Response DIV fills with returned HTML
3. Response DIV fades in nicely.

My main "contact us" form, however, is the odd one out... the response DIV immediately appears with no fade effects.

I have read that I should first "hide()" the DIV - which I have tried without any success and nothing seems to work.

I have noticed that if I return purely text (echoed by PHP) then the fade works.... but when I try to get it to output any HTML tags then it all fails and the DIVs appear immediately...

My Form response:

`<div><span id="contactUsAjaxResponse"></span><div>`

My jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contactUsForm").submit(function(){
var responseDiv = '#contactUsAjaxResponse';
// add ajax-loader class to response div
$(responseDiv).html('').addClass('ajax-loader');
// get form actiom
var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
$.post(formAction, $("#contactUsForm").serializeArray(), function(data){
$(responseDiv).removeClass('ajax-loader').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
});
return false; //prevent default form action
});
});
```

Any echoed HTML is `<php echo '<div class="error">Content...</div>'; ?>` etc.

I have a feeling it could be my CSS (could any `display: block;` or other entries be causing the problem?)

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you post your html for me? Maybe at http://jsfiddle.net/ you can work an example of what you have over there so I can see here.

Comment: I never knew jsfiddle.net existed! This tool is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way (imo) is to have the result-div (that you call error) already present on your webpage. Hide it with css using `display: none` and make it empty. When the result is retreived, use fadeIn('slow') on that element.

The base line is that there is no point in hiding a div using js, and then show it later. This can simply be done using css

Comment: Ah, now this is where I forgot to add something... I have two different classes of div... "error" and "success"... red/green respectively.

Comment: Sorry, pressing "Enter" submits on this site... my bad. My PHP outputs the the div with the class. But it already places it into an existing `<span>` (my "`ajaxResponse`") - e.g. `<span id="ajaxResponse"></span>`

Comment: The set the style of the div using css before you display it? Less elements is better

Comment: A sample output would be: `<span id="ajaxResponse"><div class="error">An error occurred</div></span>` - the entire "<div>" is created using PHP - but not the <span> - this is coded on the form.

Comment: Alternatively: `<span id="ajaxResponse"><div class="success">Form submitted</div></span>` - I'd like the response to fadeIn, and then, after a few seconds delay, fadeOut.

Comment: Hmm... for some reason it is all now working... I am really quite confused here!

Comment: Thanks OptimusCrime, I re-read your response and thought that I'd clean up my form and changed the response `<span>` to a `<div>` = I believe it was this that got the ball rolling for it to work.